# Winform split up string in a text box

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

Sorry, newb question that I can't seem to work out.

I'm connecting to a server via a php file that is return a list of the files held on there like so:

> 511157.jpg|Koala.jpg|VIDEO0031.3gp|test_folder.folder

However I want my text box to display them like so

> 511157.jpg
>
> Koala.jpg
>
> VIDEO0031.3gp
>
> test_folder.folder

I've been trying this at the moment but it isn't doing what I'm wanting it to do:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

I know this is a simple thing to do, but I can't seem to get my head to function properly. Could someone please help me out?

I should note I have no idea what the files will be on the server. I'm getting this information by calling the following:

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
             result = client.DownloadString("http://server.foo.com/images/getDirectoryList.php");
        }
```

Anything could be on this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if a filename contains the pipe character?

Comment: A legal file name cant contain a pipe character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the text first:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Split('|'));
```

Comment: I just tried this but it only returns my original line minus the pipe. Is there something I should change in my textbox for it go onto a new line?

Comment: @Sean You likely need to set your `TextBox`s `Multiline` property to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by the pipe character first, then join:

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, "511157.jpg|Koala.jpg|VIDEO0031.3gp|test_folder.folder".Split('|'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use Regex.Replace() for that simple case:

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace("511157.jpg|Koala.jpg|VIDEO0031.3gp|test_folder.folder", "\\|", "\r\n")
```

Comment: string.Replace is also great idea. Just my preference. When I am using a regex, I also want to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
textBox1.Lines = result.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this  by .split as

```
String s=511157.jpg|Koala.jpg|VIDEO0031.3gp|test_folder.folder;

textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s.Split('|'));
```

Comment: Pretty sure he wants to split on pipe, not space.